# Show that $\frac{1}{x+2}$ is continuous for $(-2,0]$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

I must use an $ε-δ$ proof to prove the function $\frac{1}{x+2}$ is continuous for $(-2,0]$.

I set $x \in (-2,0]$, and $y\in (-2,0]$ s.t $|x-y|<δ$.

I am having a hard time determining what precisely I should set $y$ to, as

$|\frac{1}{x+2}-\frac{1}{y+2}|=|\frac{(y+2)-(x+2)}{(x+2)(y+2)}|=\frac{|y-x|}{(x+2)(y+2)}$

and at this point I am stuck on how to proceed.

Comment: you have to prove that the function is continuous for all $x\in(-2,0]$. Start by fixing an $\epsilon > 0$ and try to find $\delta$ such that the continuity condition holds.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

For $\vert y-x \vert \le \frac{x +2}{2}$ you have

$$-\frac{x +2}{2} \le y-x \le \frac{x +2}{2}, \text{ hence } 2 + y \ge \frac{x}{2} + 1 = \frac{x+2}{2}$$

and therefore

$$0 \le \frac{1}{2+y} \le \frac{2}{2+x}$$

Finally

$$\left\vert\frac{1}{x+2}-\frac{1}{y+2}\right\vert=\left\vert\frac{(y+2)-(x+2)}{(x+2)(y+2)}\right\vert=\frac{|y-x|}{(x+2)(y+2)} \le \frac{2}{(x+2)^2} \vert y-x\vert$$

For $\epsilon >0$ given, $\delta = \min\{\frac{x+2}{2}, \frac{\epsilon (x+2)^2}{2}\}$ should do the job.